# Bluetooth module (BLE112) USART: do I need to use its own microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am looking into the [this module](https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/RefNotes/BLE112_Datasheet1.pdf).

All I need it for in my design is USART connection to my MCU (TX/RX connections). I don't care for the internal microcontroller (yet).

My question: if I connect, with my host MCU, TX <---> RX and vise versa, do I need to use the BLE112 internal microcontroller at all to initialize functionality, or can I just be up and running with my host MCU over USART?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the internal MCU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the block diagram on page 20 of your linked datasheet, you'll see that all of the I/O, including the USARTs, go to the 8051 controller. The 8051, in turn, is the only path to the Bluetooth radio section.

Therefore, I'd say that the internal microcontroller is required for the module to function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page which has a datasheet. http://www.inmojo.com/store/electronic-system-design/item/usb-ble112/ The BLE112 module will need to be first programmed as a master or slave at the correct baud rate. Then the MCU can simply send data out its UART/USART. The BLE112 module will take care of any connections and will appear as a wired connection (even though it is wireless) if the other BLE device is within 30cm or whatever the receiving range is. An antenna will dramatically increase the range.